# Declare var in typescript from external file gets ReferenceError: ... is not defined

Tags: javascript, variables, typescript

I have the following typescript file-->

```
module someModule {
declare var servicePort: string;

export class someClass{
constructor(){
  servicePort = servicePort || ""; //ERROR= 'ReferenceError: servicePort is not defined'
}
```

also tried this on one of functions inside "someClass" -->

```
someFunction = () => {
    if (servicePort && servicePort != '') { //ERROR - also servicePort is not defined
            //do something with servicePort 
        }
}
```

If I define var servicePort somewhere on my js /html files it will work, but not all my pages contains the servicePort var, and I want to safe get the value from that varible without exception.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, it's `'use strict';`.

Comment: I've tried removing it, still acts the same

Comment: If you compile this TypeScript code into JavaScript you will see that `declare` has no effect in real code.

Comment: Yes i know, it is only to let typescript know that I have a var called servicePort and I want to use it.

Comment: ...but you clearly *don't* have a var `servicePort` if you're seeing that error!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a variable sometimes be defined and sometimes not is a pretty big code smell, but if you *really* want to do this, you need to guard access on that variable with `typeof`:

```
if (typeof servicePort !== "undefined") {
   // safe to use servicePort here
}
```

Note that you won't be able to tell the difference between a *missing* variable and one with the value `undefined`, but such is life.

Comment: Ok it seems descent enough solution, I'll test it @Sunday. I know that it is not 'best practice' to use this var only on some pages, can you suggest an alternative? I have some pages that uses a servicePort and some that don't. I can place 'var servicePort = ""'' on my master layout but I fear from that. Can you think of an idea?